# C static struct declaration directive

Tags: c, struct, preprocessor

I'm trying to declare a static C struct. The declaration of the struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c
}dummy_struct;
```

However when making the definition of the struct, I want to store a value in c that is calculated using the values in a and b and another constant value.

My initial idea was to store it this way:

```
static dummy_struct dummy = 
{
    .a = 5,
    .b = 10,
    .c = CALC_VALUE(0.5, a, b)
}
```

And then I would define CALC_VALUE as a preprocessor so that I could run some calulations on a, b and the constant value like so:

```
#define CALC_VALUE(constant, a, b) (constant * (a/2) * (b*3))
```

But my compiler complains every time I do this so I'm resorting to the following method for the declaration:

```
static dummy_struct dummy = 
{
    .a = 5,
    .b = 10,
    .c = CALC_VALUE(0.5, 5, 10)
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this without using #defines for 'a' and 'b'

Comment: Why not just store `0.5` in the struct, and then do the calculation where you need the value?

Comment: Structure members are not variables, they can't be accessed without referring to the variable containing the struct.

Comment: And you can only use literals and constant expressions when initializing a static variable.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica The problem is not storing 0.5, it is about being able to access the value in a and b from within the struct declaration. I don't mind using a #define for 0.5, but I want to be able to access a and b as they are both already defined for the struct member. So I was wondering if there is a way to access the value stored in the local member. If you look at my second code snippet, I want to be able to do something like that.

Comment: @Barmar Ok got it. That is the limitation I'm trying to get past I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use a macro to generate the entire initial value of the struct.

```
#define CALC_VALUE(constant, a_val, b_val) { \
    .a = (a_val), \
    .b = (b_val), \
    .c = ((constant) * ((a_val)/2) * ((b_val)*3)) \
}
```

Then you can do:

```
static dummy_struct dummy = CALC_VALUE(0.5, 5, 10);
```